# Pointwise and uniform convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\big({\frac{x}{1+x^n}}\big)^n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, uniform-convergence, pointwise-convergence

Examine the convergence of  the series of functions
$$\displaystyle\mathop{\sum}\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}\Big({\frac{x}{1+x^n}}\Big)^n$$
 a) pointwise   in $[0,1]$,

b) uniformly in $[0,1]$.

My attempt for  pointwise convergence: For all $x\in[0,1)$ exists $n_0(x)\in{\mathbb{N}}$ such that for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ with $n\geqslant n_0(x)$ :
$$\displaystyle\Big|\Big({\frac{x}{1+x^n}}\Big)^n\Big|<\frac{1}{n^2}\,.$$
Because $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, we have that the series  $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\big({\frac{x}{1+x^n}}\big)^n$ converges pointwise in  $[0,1)$. Also for  $x=1$ :  $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\big({\frac{1}{1+1^n}}\big)^n=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\big({\frac{1}{2}}\big)^n=1$.
So, the series converges pointwise in $[0,1]$.

I have no answer for uniform convergence.

**edit: This is not an answer for the uniform convergence issue.** I'm just giving two plots which shows the behavior of the partial sums sequence $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\big({\frac{x}{1+x^k}}\big)^k$ near $1$, where is possible the non-uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\big({\frac{x}{1+x^n}}\big)^n$, for helping others to procced further. In the rest of the interval the series looks that converges uniformly. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hint: Optimze the function $x\mapsto \frac{x}{1+x^{n}}$ on [0,1]

Comment: @TheOscillator The sequence of functions $f_n(x):=\frac{x}{1+x^n}\,,\; n\in\mathbb{N}\,,$  does not converges uniformly on $[0,1]$. But how  can we use that for the uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\big(f_n(x)\big)^n$ ? There exists a big gap between these two.

Comment: That’s interesting !  I don’t see how this question is off topic !!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$$\sqrt[n]{\left(\frac x{1+x^n}\right)^n} =\frac x{1+x^n}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\begin{cases}x,&x\in[0,1)\\{}\\
\cfrac12,&x=1\end{cases}$$

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why this hint tell us something about uniform convergence.

Comment: For pointwise convergence: For all $x\in[0,1)$ exists  $n_0(x)\in{\mathbb{N}}$, such that for all $n\in{\mathbb{N}}$ with $n\geqslant n_0(x)$ :  
 $$\displaystyle\Big|\Big({\frac{x}{1+x^n}}\Big)^n\Big|<\frac{1}{n^2}\,.$$
 Because $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$, we have that the series  $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\big({\frac{x}{1+x^n}}\big)^n$ converges pointwise in $[0,1)$. Also  
  $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\big({\frac{1}{1+1^n}}\big)^n=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\big({\frac{1}{2}}\big)^n=1$. So, the series converges point wise in $[0,1]$.

Comment: @GrigoriosKostakos The hint tells you there's pointwise convergence if $\;0\le x<1\;$ , but divergence if $\;x=1\;$ ...This already tells you stuff about  u.c., doesn't it?

Comment: No, does not. As stated above the series converges at $x=1$ because $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\big({\frac{1}{1+1^n}}\big)^n=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\big({\frac{1}{2}}\big)^n=1$. Does not diverges. So, uniform convergence remains open.

Comment: @GrigoriosKostakos Good point, it is true. Then the OP will still need to make an evaluation as he tried to do from the beginning...and in fact that'll be his answer.